# How is TFS 2010 used within Microsoft for scrum sprinting?

Tags: tfs, scrum

We are a Microsoft shop, and so using other incompatible tools for Scrum does not make as much sense. So, we use `TFS` - for Scrum as well.

However, we found `TFS` templates to be rather simplistic. There is no way that `MSFT` can release the next Visual Studio, or the next .Net framework by doing all of the planning using TFS tasks.

What is Microsoft hiding from the rest of the world?
Alternatively, how do you use TFS 2010 for scrum in enterprise (=huge size) software?

***EDIT:*** Specifically, trying to figure out how different pieces fit together can be hard. Imagine the following epic (as if it was developed in .Net 5.0 and not done in .net 3.5): We want to implement the LINQ library. Now, let us size this task ... before the can do so, they need to carefully define all of the stories **IN DETAIL**, and only then try to put it together. Still, the amount of use cases is huge, and interactions between different parts of the system. Without lots of Wiki pages, lots of Word documents, a combination of these two, and perhaps something else, I do not see how they could keep track of things.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has released a new scrum template for 2010.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/06/07/a-scrum-process-template-for-tfs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's a 9 post series on the old TeamsWitTools blog about how dev-div uses TFS.  The [first post in the series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/teams_wit_tools/archive/2008/03/27/how-microsoft-devdiv-uses-tfs-chapter-1-our-process.aspx) talks about the breakdown of epics.  This is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I should also mention Sam Guckenhiemer (DevDiv) did a presentation on Agile in the Very Large at the Australian ALM Summit earlier this year.  You can find the slide deck at http://www.australianalm.com.au/presentations/Agile%20in%20the%20Very%20Large.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TFS 2010, but I do know that the TFS 2008 has some important features to Scrum.

Once setup correctly, TFS can launch a bunch of tasks automatically for huge scale projects, which Scrum was founded to manage very productively. Some of these tasks is to compile a build at scheduled time. In the case of Scrum, I would say after each Sprint, after that the commitments of the Team has been done. "Done" is a very important word in Scrum, this means that here is nothing left to be done. So, think of it as all of the kind of testing, test automation, etc. is done. Your code works, 150% sure, bug free. Anyway, TFS can report the tests that failed, and track down who this task was assigned to (Team, not individual).

After having taken an eye out to @Shiraz Bhaiji's link, I think that FS 2010 got all what you need with Scrum. You got the Burndown chart, which purpose is to illustrate the work remaining to be done throughout the time, you got the velocity chart, which gives significant information about the Team's velocity to work together. Keep in mind that the velocity of a Team shall augment with the time the Team works together.

I see no problem at all using TFS2010 and set it up to work with Scrum, as it can track the Product Backlog, and should allow you to write Team's Sprint Backlog as well. In fact, there is now, with the coming of VS2010, the PSD certification, which is Professional Scrum Developer certification.

Microsoft Developers Tools (TFS and VS) is Scrum "compatible".